# Measuring how similar my post-processing distribution is to an expected distribution, for messy/multi-modal relationships

Tags: distributions, clustering, similarities

I have an 'expected distribution' between two variables X,Y that I have observed for 54000 examples. An example distribution that I observe between these variables looks like this:

[image]

Through some software, I process separate examples such that I generate a new dataset containing a 'processed distribution'. Which may look something like this, for example:

[image]

Originally I was measuring how successfully the software was able to generate a dataset which has a similar form to what I expect, by ensuring that the correlations that I get are the same. However, this clearly doesn't make sense in cases like this where the distribution is multi-modal, messy and/or non-linear.

I was then thinking that I could determine the function that maps X to Y, and then ensure that this function is satisfied by the data points in my processed set. However, I am not sure of any techniques which can map a single X to multiple defined Ys, in the case of (for example) two clear relationships between the variables.

Is there any metric which I could use to judge that these two distributions are similar?

I can clearly see that:

- The shapes of the distributions are similar (Y increases for a fixed X near 900, and X increases for a fixed Y around 2000).
- Some of the data is missing, particularly some of higher X-values are not found in the processed dataset

I can't think of any sensible metric which would reflect the above, and hopefully increase as the problems are alleviated e.g. as my processed distribution incorporates the higher X value ranges at Y ~ 2000, the metric would increase (although if these higher-X examples also had a wildly different Y e.g. 5000, I would lose 'similarity').

Thanks very much for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need multiple distance measures. You could use the Kullback Liebler Divergence to see how different the shape is and to see if the probability of being missing is the same: you can calculate the empirical probability of data being missing and compare it to what the number should be.

Comment: Hi, this is interesting - thanks for pointing me in this direction. My concern is that I do not think my data is normally distributed in each dimension, but I will look into it further.

Answer (score 0):

Sample subsets of the *same size* from each distribution.

Join the data into one data set.

For every point, find the nearest other sample. How often is it of the same origin data set?

Compare this to the urn model.

If you cannot tell whether you are drawing nearest neighbors or from the urn model, then your two data sets follow the same distribution.